# Change directory and run command in ConEmu tasks

Tags: bash, git-bash, conemu

I'm trying to create ConEmu task in Cmder, I want to navigate to particular directory and run a SSH command and using `git-bash` for this. I'm able to change directory but can't run the SSH command.

Command

```
*cmd /c "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login -i  -new_console:d:E:\Project\SSHKeys && ssh -i "secret.pem" ubuntu@ip_address
```

Error

`'C:\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login -i && ssh -i "secret.pem' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here

1. You are SSH-ing to remote server, it doesn't care on your local directory. Why do you want that?
2. You don't need cmd.exe to run bash command. Don't add spare layers of processed. They have no sense.
3. Even if you need to run something via `cmd /c ...` you have to learn how cmd does unquoting. You have to add one more double quote around your command line `cmd /c ""something" ... & ..."`